# Javascript-escape special characters in xml

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a n xml which has the string "/" in it multiple times I need to replace it with "/" can somebody help with the regex.

i tried :

```
Val.replace(\//g, '/')
```

But that doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex format isn't quite right, you have:

```
Val.replace(\//g, '/')
```

When JS regex is always between the '/' characters, like so:

```
/<REGEXGOESHERE>/g
```

In your case you are looking for (I think, your message is slightly confusing as it says you want to replace '/' with '/' which doesn't make sense, so I assumed you were saying replace '\' with '/')

```
Val.replace(/[\]/g, '/')
```

Here's a useful tool for debugging regex:

http://regexr.com/